# Azure Functions Credential uses wrong tenant

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am trying to run Azure Function written in python from VSCode.
No matter what I try, I get this error or similar - always the same tenant which I have no idea where it came from.

Various ways of getting credential:

```
credential = AzureCliCredential(tenant_id=os.environ["AZURE_TENANT_ID"])
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
credential = EnvironmentCredential()
```

I have also tried to set **local.settings.json** (which sets environment variables)

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AZURE_TENANT_ID": "ad8d36e3-7a5d-4687-bef3-e758fc4f7649",
    "AZURE_CLIENT_ID":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "AZURE_AUTHORITY_HOST":"login.microsoftonline.com"
  }
}
```

**Error**:
*The current credential is not configured to acquire tokens for tenant **49793faf-eb3f-4d99-a0cf-aef7cce79dc1.** To enable acquiring tokens for this tenant add it to the additionally_allowed_tenants when creating the credential, or add "*" to additionally_allowed_tenants to allow acquiring tokens for any tenant.*

It consistently uses the wrong tenant which sometimes appears as "American Airlines" in other error messages.

I have also tried where os.environ["AZURE_TENANT_ID"] tests as '**ad8d36e3-7a5d-4687-bef3-e758fc4f7649**':

```
credential = 
ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=os.environ["AZURE_TENANT_ID"],                                       
    client_id=os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_ID"],                                        
    client_secret=os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"] )
```

**Error**:
*The current credential is not configured to acquire tokens for tenant **49793faf-eb3f-4d99-a0cf-aef7cce79dc1**. To enable acquiring tokens for this tenant add it to the additionally_allowed_tenants when creating the credential, or add "*" to additionally_allowed_tenants to allow acquiring tokens for any tenant.*

I have cleared out all the various Azure logins, so the DefaultAzureCredential fails not finding any login configurations.

I have tried:
az login --tenant-id xxx
azd auth login
etc...

This worked recently, and then I had to reboot.

Where is the login logic pulling tenant **49793faf-eb3f-4d99-a0cf-aef7cce79dc1.** from ?
How do I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Tenant ID in `Visual Studio Code=>Settings=>Search for *Tenant*` has your latest and valid Tenant ID.

- If it has wrong Tenant ID, update with the current ID, Sign-Out and Sign In again for the modifications to reflect.

[image]

- Check the current logged in User with the command az account show:

[image]

- **Try using** `DefaultAzureCredential(additionally_allowed_tenants=['*'])` **instead of** `DefaultAzureCredential()`.

Refer [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/26602#issuecomment-1265954683).

***Code Snippet:***

```py
app = func.FunctionApp()
@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    credential = DefaultAzureCredential(additionally_allowed_tenants=["<Tenant_ID"])
    scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    token = credential.get_token(scope)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, token is {token}")
```

**Console Output:**

```py
(.venv) C:\Users\vname\pyfuncn>func start
Found Python version 3.11.8 (py).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5455 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.27.5.21554
[2024-03-01T07:11:01.816Z] Customer packages not in sys path. This should never happen!
[2024-03-01T07:11:03.401Z] Worker process started and initialized.
Functions:
        http_trigger:  http://localhost:7071/api/http_trigger
        
For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-03-01T07:11:08.296Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-03-01T07:11:08.456Z] Executing 'Functions.http_trigger' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=10449adb-9e3a-4eaf-a2ed-ca8b196dbfcb)
[2024-03-01T07:11:08.523Z] Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-03-01T07:11:09.183Z] Environment is configured for ClientSecretCredential
[2024-03-01T07:11:09.202Z] ManagedIdentityCredential will use IMDS
[2024-03-01T07:11:09.203Z] Request URL: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/2773f7fdXXXXXXXXX5719f9b0b/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'
Request method: 'GET'
Request headers:
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-identity/1.15.0 Python/3.11.8 (Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0)'
No body was attached to the request
[2024-03-01T07:11:11.595Z] Response status: 200
Response headers:
        [Removed few logs]
[2024-03-01T07:11:12.241Z] DefaultAzureCredential acquired a token from EnvironmentCredential
[2024-03-01T07:11:12.317Z] Executed 'Functions.http_trigger' (Succeeded, Id=10449adXXXXXXXXXX-ca8b196dbfcb, Duration=3884ms)
```

**Response:**

[image]